# Can I enable TCPKeepAlive with paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

How can I get paramiko to do the equivalent of setting "TCPKeepAlive yes" in `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it: `Transport.set_keepalive`.  Use in conjunction with the `timeout` argument to `SSHClient.connect` to set the socket timeout.